# How to retrieve large sets of data accross multiple tables and avoid a looping queries

Tags: mysql

First sorry if the question was already answered, I searched both here and Google and couldn't find my answer. This question can't possibly haven't been asked, but it is hidden pretty deep under all the "Just use LEFT JOIN" and "store it in an array" answers.

I need to load a lot of data spread across multiple tables (then insert it into another database engine, but that's not important, I need to optimize my SELECTs).

The table layout looks like this:

Table A with a_id field
Table B with a_id and b_id field
Table C with b_id and c_id field
... (goes another 3-4 levels like this).

I currently access the data this way (pseudo code):

```
query1 = SELECT ... FROM TableA WHERE something=$something

foreach query1 as result1:

    query2 = SELECT ... FROM TableB WHERE b_id=result1.a_id

    foreach query2 as result2:
        query3 = SELECT ... FROM TableC WHERE bc_id=result2.b_id

            foreach query3 as result3:
                // Another few levels of this, see the millions of SELECTs coming?
```

The only solutions I have found so far are:

1. Use the slow way and send multiple queries (current solution, and it takes ages to complete my small test set)
2. Use a ton of LEFT JOIN to have all the data in one query. Involves transmitting a ton of data thousands of times and so some fancy logic on client side to split this into their appropriate tables again since each row will contain the content of its parent tables. (I use OOP and each table maps to an object, and each object contains each-other).
3. Store each object from table A in an array, then load all Table B, store into an array, continue on Table C. Works for small sets, but mine is a few GB large, won't fit into ram at all.

Is there a way to avoid doing 10k queries per second in such a loop?

(I'm using PHP, converting from MySQL to MongoDB which handles nested objects like this way better, if this helps)

EDIT: There seem to have some confusions about what I'm trying to do and why. I will try to explain better: I need to do a batch conversion to a new structure. The new structure works very well, don't even bother looking on that. I'm remaking a very old website from scratch, and chose MongoDB as my storage engine because we have loads of nested data like this, and it works very well for me. Switching back to MySQL is not even an option for me, the new structure and code is alreay well established and I've been working on this for about a year now. **I am not looking in a way to optimize the current schema, I can't.** The data is that way, and I need to read the whole database. Once. Then I'm done with it.

**All I need to do**, is to import the data from the old website, process this and convert it so I can insert it into our new website. Here comes MySQL: The older site was a very normal PHP/MySQL site. We have a lot of tables (about 70 actually or something). We don't have many users, but each users have a ton of data spanned on 7 tables.

**What I currently do**, is that I loop on each user (1 query). For each of these users (70k), I load Table A which contains 10-80 rows for each user. I then query Table B on every loop of A (so, 10-80 times 70k), which contains 1-16 rows for each A. There comes Table C, which holds 1-4 rows for each B. We are now at 4*80*70k queries to do. Then I have D, 1-32 rows for each C. E with 1-16 rows for each D. F with 1-16 rows for each E. Table F has a couple of millions rows.

**Problem** is

- I end up doing thousands if not millions of queries to the MySQL server, where the production database is not even on my local machine, but 5-10ms away. Even at 0.01ms, I have hours just in network latency. I created a local replica so my restricted test set runs quite faster, but it's still going to take a long while to download a few GB of data like this.
- I could keep the members table in RAM and maybe Table A so I can download each database in one shot instead of doing thousands of queries, but once at Table B and further it would be a real mess to track this in memory, especially since I use PHP (command line, at least), which uses a bit more memory than if it was a C++ program where I could have tight RAM control. So this solution doesn't work either.
- I could JOIN all the tables together, but if it works for 2-3 tables, doing this for 7 tables would result in an extra huge bandwidth loss transferring the same data from the server millions of times without a use (while also making the code really complicated to split them back in the appropriate order).

**Question is**: Is there a way to not query the database so often? Like, telling the MySQL server with a procedure or something that I will need all these datasets in this order so I don't have to re-do a query each row and so the database just continually spits out data for me? The current problem is just that I do so much queries that both the script AND the database are almost idle because one is always waiting for another one. The queries themselves are actually very fast, basic prepared SELECT queries on indexed int fields.

This is a problem I always got myself into with MySQL in the past, which never really caused me trouble until now. In its current state, the script takes several hours if not days to complete. It's not THAT bad, but if there's a way I can do better I'd appreciate to know. If not, then okay, I'll just wait for it to finish, at least it will run max 3-4 times (2-3 test runs, have users check their data is converted correctly, fix bugs, try again, and the final run with the last bugfixes).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the resultset is to large for `(3)` (which otherwise would have been my advise if `(2)` is to hefty), well, you are indeed stuck with (1) with your 'small test set', or upgrade your RAM. If however your database server itself has plenty of ram to spare, you might try `(3)` in several unbuffered connections instead of 1 connection, fetching only what you need when you need it.

Comment: What is your "new storage solution"?  If it's the same table layout in a different database you'd approach it differently to one that does a lot of transformations.  It's not clear what you do at the client side.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @LoztInSpace I completely remade the website using a different storage solution called MongoDB. It's a NoSQL type, document oriented database. Long story short, it stores the whole structure as a single row, which is much more convenient in my case since I always need the whole structure for display, and it is a single, super fast operation while keeping the structure. I mentionned that in my question too, "converting from MySQL to MongoDB". I usually only use NoSQL, but I have to import the old data.

I will probably just end up running a local db so the latency doesn't kill the speed...

Comment: @Max-P sorry mate - I completely manage to overlook your MongoDB stuff in the question :( Have you tried exporting as CSV and loading it in using http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#bin.mongoimport

Comment: @LoztInSpace It's more complicated than that. I really need to fully rebuild the thing in PHP to insert this properly. CSV is still only rows and won't help me at all in this case, actually it would be worse because I'd have to really load it all in RAM, which is not possible (too large). I mentionned MongoDB to help understand _why_ I need to process that much data, but the MongoDB part is already working perfectly. I'm trying to speed up the import process because it takes about 5 minutes for my 10 test accounts. I have to run that on 70k accounts, at least :/

Comment: No idea then.  70k rows is trivial.  Unless each row (and related row) represents gigabytes of XML or something I am at a total loss to explain the poor performance.  Even MS Access should be able to handle that much data with ease were it not for the limit on file size.  If you can find what's taking so long for your 10 records then you can fix your export and possibly remove the need to move to MongoDB (unless you want to for other reasons of course).  If you show a bit more of your relational and MongoDB structures then I can offer more help perhaps.

Comment: @LoztInSpace The poor performance is mainly because I have to do thousands of queries per seconds. Server is 8ms away, 8ms each request*70k = hours only on the first level. I created a replica for now, it's a bit faster. I will probably end up being really patient. The 70k rows is the starting point: Table A holds 70k rows. Table B holds 50 rows for each A. Table C have 4-6 rows for each B. Table D have about 2-4 rows for each C. Table E have about 24 rows for each D. Table F has about 6-12 rows for each E. Table G has about 1-8 for each F. I thought I could batch-query this in a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the anwers. I came to the conclusion that I can't actually do it any other way.

My own solution is to set up a replica database (or just a copy if a snapshot is enough) on localhost. That way, it cuts down the network latency and allows both the script and the database to reach 100% CPU usage, and it seems to be the fastest I can get without reorganizing my script entirely.

Of course, this only works for one-time scripts. The correct way to handle this would be a mix of both answers I got as of now: use multiple unbuffered connections in threads, and process by batch (load 50 rows from Table A, store in ram, load all data related to Table A from Table B, store in RAM, then process all that and continue from Table A).

Thanks anyway for the answers all!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 7 tables are linked by ids, do something like this

First query

```
'SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE a_id IN (12,233,4545,67676,898999)'
// store the result in $result_of_first_query
```

Then do a foreach and pick the ids you want to use in the next query in a comma separated variable (csv)

```
foreach($result_of_first_query as $a_row_from_first_table)
{
    $csv_for_second_query = $csv_for_second_query.$a_row_from_first_table['b_id'].",";
}

$csv_for_second_query = trim($csv_for_second_query,", "); // problem is we will have a lot of duplicate entries
$temp_arr = array(); // so lets remove the duplicates
$temp_arr = explode(",",$csv_for_second_query);  // explode values in array
$temp_arr = array_unique($temp_arr);  // remove duplicates
$csv_for_second_query = implode(",",$temp_arr);  // create csv string again. ready!
```

now for your second table, you will get, with only 1 query all the values you need to JOIN (not by mysql, we will do this with php)

Second query

```
'SELECT * FROM table_b where a_id IN ('.$csv_for_second_query.')'
// store the result in $result_of_second_query;
```

Then we just need to programmatically join the two arrays.

```
$result_a_and_b = array(); // we will store the joined result of every row here

// lets scan every row from first table
foreach($result_of_first_query as $inc=> $a_row_from_first_table)
{
    // assign every row from frist table to result_a_and_b 
    $result_a_and_b[$inc]['a']=$a_row_from_first_table;

    $inc_b=0; // counter for the joins that will happen by data from second table

    // for every row from first table we will scan every row from second table
    // so we need this nested foreach
    foreach($result_of_second_query as $a_row_from_second_table)
    {
        // are data need to join? if yes then do so! :)
        if($a_row_from_first_table['a_id']==$a_row_from_second_table['a_id'])
        {
            $result_a_and_b[$inc]['b'][$inc_b]=$a_row_from_second_table; // "join" in our "own" way :)
            ++$inc_b; // needed for the next join
        }
    }
}
```

now we have the array $result_a_and_b with this format:

```
$result_a_and_b[INDEX]['a']
$result_a_and_b[INDEX]['b'][INDEX]
```

so with 2 queries, we have a result similar to TABLE_A_ROWS_NUMBER + 1 (one is the initial query of first table)

Like this keep doing as many levels you want.

1. Query database with the id that links the table
2. get the id's in CSV string
3. do query in next able using WHERE id IN(11,22,33,44,55,.....)
4. join programmatically

Tip: You can use `unset()` to free up memory on temp variables.

I believe i answered in your question *"Is there a way to not query the database so often?"*

note: code not tested for typos, maybe i missed a comma or two -or maybe not

i believe you can get the point :) hope it helps!

Comment: Thats basically my solution `(3)` and it won't work because the tables are too big to be loaded into arrays. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Max-P 1) if tables are too big you can put a limit on the first query e.g. 100 per time, and do this as many times as needed. then problem solved. you dont have to do "10k queries per second". 2) As for the "extra huge bandwidth loss" if you want data pre-proccessed ready to be imported, then this way is the OPTIMUM way to save bandwidth. You can also save the result in a compressed file and send it over to the importer script. 3) code really complicated: i don't think it's complicated. Of course i dont have complete knowledge of your situation, i just respond based on what you have described

Comment: @Max-P and of course, if this is a 1 time conversion, and you have 2 days to spare, just let it run for 2 days and its over. And especially if its safe and the integrity of the data is guaranteed. Better to wait 2 days than program 2 days, debug another 2 days and then fix badly converted data for the rest of your life. :)