# outer Join query through cursors

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, left-join

I have the following query:

```
(
     select  f.Product, bpsrelation.bps, f.Week ForecastWeek, 
             f.FC Forecast, `Order qty`  quantity, 
             s.FC Sales, s.Week salesWeek, s.`Plant Code`, f.`APO Location` 
     from forecastnew f
     right outer join bpsrelation on bpsrelation.Product = f.Product
     right outer join sales s on bpsrelation.bps = s.BPS and f.Week = s.Week 
                             and s.`PLant Code` = f.`APO Location`
     right outer join orders on orders.Product = f.Product
     group by s.Week, s.`PLant Code`,s.Customer,s.bps
) 
union
(
     select  f.Product, bpsrelation.bps, f.Week ForecastWeek, 
             f.FC Forecast, `Order qty`     quantity, 
             s.FC Sales, s.Week salesWeek, s.`Plant Code`, f.`APO Location` 
     from forecastnew f
     left outer join orders on orders.Product = f.Product
     left outer join bpsrelation on bpsrelation.Product = f.Product
     left outer join sales s on bpsrelation.bps = s.BPS 
                             and f.Week = s.Week and s.`PLant Code` = f.`APO Location`
     where f.`APO Location` is null
     group by s.Week, f.`APO Location`, s.Customer,s.bps
);
```

The explain extended is as follows:

```
1   PRIMARY orders  ALL                 33335   100.00  Using         temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY f   ref idx_forecastnew_Product idx_forecastnew_Product 23          demandplaning.orders.Product    103 100.00  
1   PRIMARY bpsrelation ref idx_bpsrelation_Product,idx_bpsrelation_bps idx_bpsrelation_Product 23  demandplaning.f.Product 1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY s   ref idx_sales_BPS   idx_sales_BPS   33  demandplaning.bpsrelation.bps   41  100.00  Using where
2   UNION   f   ALL                 329325  100.00  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   UNION   orders  ref idx_orders_Product  idx_orders_Product  23  demandplaning.f.Product 64  100.00  
2   UNION   bpsrelation ref idx_bpsrelation_Product idx_bpsrelation_Product 23  demandplaning.f.Product 1   100.00  
2   UNION   s   ref idx_sales_BPS   idx_sales_BPS   33  demandplaning.bpsrelation.bps   41  100.00  Using where
    UNION RESULT    <union1,2>  ALL                             Using temporary
```

The forecast and the sales table need to be joined by plant code, week and product.
This takes a lot of time. I searched stackoverflow and internet, it is adviced to do this with foreach or cursor. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: These table have 3 lac rows per table. I think thats why the query is taking so. As can be seen in the explain extended i have indexed them all but still no speed enhancement.

Comment: Where did you find this advice ? Could you post a link to it ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158314/how-to-retrieve-large-sets-of-data-accross-multiple-tables-and-avoid-a-looping-q) this is where i read about it. Do you have any other idea in mind?